# ROBLOX | Argument 1 missing or nil?

Tags: lua, roblox

I haven't got too much of experience in lua so I am here to ask for help. I am currently making a script for a game called ROBLOX, but I have came across a problem in my script and it is coming from this little part here

```
me.Chatted:connect(function(msg)
    if string.sub(msg,1,5) == "!kick" then
        local PLAYER = (''.. string.sub(msg,6))
        KICK('game.Players.PLAYER')
    end
end)
```

(The error I am getting is: **Argument 1 missing or nil**)

I am sort of lost on what to do, but here is the rest of my script..

```
local me = game.Players.LocalPlayer

function KICK(PLAYER)
   spawn(
      function()
         local function SKICK()
            if 
               PLAYER.Character 
               and PLAYER.Character:FindFirstChild('HumanoidRootPart') 
               and PLAYER.Character:FindFirstChild('Torso') 
            then
               local SP = Instance.new('SkateboardPlatform', PLAYER.Character) 
               SP.Position = Vector3.new(1000000, 1000000, 1000000) 
               SP.Transparency = 1
               PLAYER.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = SP.CFrame
               PLAYER.Character.Torso.Anchored = true
            end
         end
         spawn(
            function()
               repeat 
                  wait()
                  if PLAYER ~= nil then
                     SKICK()
                  end
               until not game:GetService('Players'):FindFirstChild(PLAYER.Name)
               if not game:GetService('Players'):FindFirstChild(PLAYER.Name) then
                  print('REMOVED ' .. PLAYER.Name)
               end
            end
         )
      end
   )
end
```

### Then this is where the error occurs

```
me.Chatted:connect(function(msg)
    if string.sub(msg,1,5) == "!kick" then
        local PLAYER = (''.. string.sub(msg,6))
        KICK('game.Players.PLAYER')
    end
end)
```

Comment: is there no line number or any other information? I'm too lazy to search all your code for possible errors. What have you done so far? you could print all variables to check which of them is nil

Comment: You're using 'game.Players.PLAYER' as a string, you should use it as an object: game.Players[PLAYER] without the quotation marks.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Answer (score 1):

In this portion of your code:

```
local PLAYER = (''.. string.sub(msg,6))
KICK('game.Players.PLAYER')
```

It looks like you made some syntax mistakes while changing your code. Here is what it should look like:

```
local PLAYER = string.sub(msg,6)
KICK('game.Players.' .. PLAYER)
```

Except this also does not make sense. You are passing the string `'game.Players.' .. PLAYER` to function `KICK()`, but `KICK()` uses its parameter `PLAYER` as though it were a Player object as seen in your use of `PLAYER.Character` and `PLAYER.Name`. You pass in a string and try to use it like a [Player](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Player) object.

One way to fix this is to pass an actual [Player](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Player) object to `KICK()` instead of a String. For example:

```
local PLAYER = string.sub(msg,6)
KICK(game:GetService('Players'):FindFirstChild('game.Players.' .. PLAYER))
```

This revision finds the Player object corresponding to the username `'game.Players.' .. PLAYER`, and then passes *that* to `KICK()`. Now, while this fixes a more obvious issue in your code, it does not exactly seem as though it will fix the issue you were referencing, "**Argument 1 missing or nil**", but you never know. If you make these changes, does it work properly?

Answer (score 1):

(sorry for replying this late)

The first problem I see on this script, is that it is a LocalScript, or atleast that is what it looks like, since you did `game.Players.LocalPlayer`. The problem with this, is that LocalScripts simply can't kick player, or harm them in any way. This is why most admins/kick commands use Server-Sided systems, in other words, Scripts instead of LocalScripts.

---

I highly suggest you to turn this into a ModuleScript or a Script, that way you can use it way easier. You know what? I'll do that for you, so no worries.

---

So, first of all, I need to know your ROBLOX name. Let's assume it is John Doe, Now, if your username is different (which certainly is quite probable), all you have to do is change John Doe to your ROBLOX Username.

Let's get to it!

---

### Turning it into a ModuleScript

Might sound as a hard task, at first, and some times, it can be, but since this script is so simple, it'll be no problem.

First, in a ModuleScript called "MainModule", paste in this code (and change John Doe to your ROBLOX Username, if it isn't John Doe.)

Note that using ModuleScripts is very useful in places like Script Builders, or even in your own games!

Also note that this ModuleScript, to work correctly, can only be ran through Scripts, not LocalScripts.

```
local username = "John Doe";

local connected = false;
local Players = game:service("Players");
local p = nil;
function kick(name)
    for _,v in pairs(Players:GetPlayers())do
        if v.Name == name then
            v:Kick("You've been kicked.");
        end;
    end;
end;

for _,v in pairs(Players:GetPlayers())do
    if v.Name == username then
        p = v;
    end;
end;

Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)
    if plr.Name == username then
        p = plr;
    end;
end;

Players.PlayerRemoving:connect(function(plr)
    if plr.Name == username then
        p = nil;
        connected = false;
    end;
end;

coroutine.wrap(function()
    while wait()do
        local r,e = ypcall(function()
            if p ~= nil then
                if not connected then
                    connected = true;
                    p.Chatted:connect(function(msg)
                        if msg:sub(1,string.len("kick"))then
                            local other = tostring(msg:sub(string.len("kick ")));
                            local search = other:lower();

                            kick(search);
                        end;
                    end);
                end;
            end;
        end);
        if e then
            warn(":ERROR: "..tostring(e));
        end;
    end;
end)();
return nil;
```

That should do it for the Module!
To execute this code, you have to follow this steps:

Firstly, create a ModuleScript inside Workspace (this is done in Roblox Studio), Now, inside the ModuleScript, paste the code I just wrote. Now, Rename this ModuleScript from "ModuleScript" to "MainModule". Now publish this script just like you would with a model.

After that, you'll see the script has a ID (for example, 12345678). This ID is located in the URL of the model. This ID is what you'll need. Copy the ID, and then, paste the ID on between the parentesys in this little script `require(<enter ID here, replacing me>);`. It should look somewhat like `require(12345678);`.

If you're willing to execute the kick script in a Script Builder, all you have to do is type the following in the chat, or in the command bar: `c/` + the `require();` I told you to do. It should look somewhat like `c/require(12345678);`. After this, just press Enter, and your kick command script will be running! All you have to do to kick a player is just say "kick " and their name! Please note that this isn't caps sensitive, but you have to wrtite the player's full name.

Example:

- kick LegendOfDarknees
- kick lEgEnDoFdArKnEes
- kick lEGENDoFdARKNEES

If you say any of these examples in the game chat after running the module, the script will try to kick a player called "LegendOfDarknees" (that's me!), though, if the player isn't on the server, the script won't do anything.

Also, note that the script will keep running in the server forever! (or until the server gets closed). This means you could try kicking yourself, or rejoining, and you'll still be able to kick players!

(please don't abuse this)

---

### Turning it into a Script (Useful for games)

There are two ways of doing this, one is by doing it the same way as I said in **Turning it into a ModuleScript**, all you'd have to do is create a Script in Workspace, inside the script, just type in `require(<ID of the module>);`. It should look somewhat like `require(12345678);`. The script will automatically execute the module, so you don't need to manually activate it.

Now, there is a alternative method, which isn't my favorite, because it is easier for a exploiter to get this script.

To do this, all you have to do is create a Script inside Workspace. Now, inside the script, paste the following code:

```
local username = "John Doe";

local connected = false;
local Players = game:service("Players");
local p = nil;
function kick(name)
    for _,v in pairs(Players:GetPlayers())do
        if v.Name == name then
            v:Kick("You've been kicked.");
        end;
    end;
end;

for _,v in pairs(Players:GetPlayers())do
    if v.Name == username then
        p = v;
    end;
end;

Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(plr)
    if plr.Name == username then
        p = plr;
    end;
end;

Players.PlayerRemoving:connect(function(plr)
    if plr.Name == username then
        p = nil;
        connected = false;
    end;
end;

coroutine.wrap(function()
    while wait()do
        local r,e = ypcall(function()
            if p ~= nil then
                if not connected then
                    connected = true;
                    p.Chatted:connect(function(msg)
                        if msg:sub(1,string.len("kick"))then
                            local other = tostring(msg:sub(string.len("kick ")));
                            local search = other:lower();

                            kick(search);
                        end;
                    end);
                end;
            end;
        end);
        if e then
            warn(":ERROR: "..tostring(e));
        end;
    end;
end)();
```

It might seem very similar to the Module one, because they're the same code, the only difference is that this one doesn't do `return nil;` at the end. This is because this script doesn't have to return something to the script that executed it, while the ModuleScript is forced to, otherwise, the ModuleScript won't run.

---

So, that should do it to answer your question. Hope you read all that, because it's quite a long text, and it might seem bored or frustating to read a long text, but this time, it's full of important information, so I highly suggest you to read it.

Again, sorry for replying this late, I wasn't able to reply before. I hope I'm not too late.

If you encounter any error/glitch/bug in the code I sent to you through this answer, feel free to let me know in the comments of this answer, I can edit the answer if you need more information, or comment your post to give you more info. Hope this replies all of your questions, and a bit more.

Good luck with your current, and with your future projects!

Comment: This is stunningly thorough and helpful! I imagine this will be an invaluable resource to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string and trying to get a name for it which is bad.

You should change `KICK('game.Players.PLAYER')` to `KICK(game:GetService("Players")[PLAYER])`

You want to pass the player object/userdata to the function not the string.

Since "game.Players.PLAYER".Name is nil the error replied "argument missing or nil"